# Remove commit of github thoroughly

Tags: git, github

I know there are thousands of threads for this question, but I still can't find out  a correctly way to remove commit thoroughly.

Yesterday, my friend send me a message,

"Hey guy, something interesting will happen if you run

> git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Fri Nov 6 20:00:00 2015 -0600"

"

I did, and push it, then [here is my github](https://github.com/zy410419243)......The timeline is weird, so I try `git reset --hard HEAD^` and push force, the commit disappeared, but the timeline not reverts.

**So my question is, how to delete this commit thoroughly to restore overview to its original state.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you managed to revert the commit but your GitHub profile is not yet updated to reflect this, then **give it some time**. Usually, it takes a while (up to a day) for GitHub to update some stuff. I had a similar experience where some statistics on GitHub were out-of-sync and it took up to a day in my case to sync.

**Edit:**
The OP figured out that correcting the error locally, deleting the repo from GitHub and reuploading it fixed the issue.

Comment: This *does not overwrite a previous commit*. In fact, *nothing* can overwrite a previous commit. The advice to wait is, however, correct.

Comment: Right: what you're doing is *replacing* commits with new-and-improved versions.  You then have to wait for GitHub to scan the replacements and update their other data. This is important, because anyone *else* who has the old commit, still has the old commit: you can't make *them* remove it. (They can remove it voluntarily, and usually will semi-automatically, when they update their clone.)

Comment: Yes. I just removed the statement entirely as it's not relevant in this specific question. Thanks for clarifying this, however, torek. (You are right as GitHub suggest that script only if you are alone on that repo.)

Comment: Finally, I remove the repo, and then push it again, and then, it seems work well.

Comment: Perfect! I think it will be a good idea to contact GitHub to let them know about this (with the reproducible steps) as it looks like a bug on their end.